# Cannot push open tags inside map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array with some elements and I want to distribute them in `ncolumns` using a `<table>`  (for simplicity suppose that nElements is a multiple of nColumns, so all rows have the same number of columns)

```
let elements = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'];
let nColumns = 3;

let nElements = elements.length;
```

So I expect to render something like:

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
J   K   L
```

I don't want to hardcode anything, so I can change the number of columns to 4 and obtain:

```
A   B   C   D
E   F   G   H
I   J   K   L
```

What I'd do is something like:

```
let toBeRendered = [];

elements.map((e, i) => {
  // For the first element of each row I open a <tr>
  if (i % nColumns == 0) {
    toBeRendered.push(<tr>);
  }

  toBeRendered.push(<td>{e}</td>);

  // For the last element of each row I close a <tr>
  if (i % nColumns == nColumns - 1) {
    toBeRendered.push(</tr>);
  }
})
```

and then inside the return:

```
return (
  <table> 
    {toBeRendered}
  </table>
);
```

I tried putting the HTML tags  and  as text (between quotes) and the generated string is correct:

```
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr><tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr><tr><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td></tr><tr><td>J</td><td>K</td><td>G</td></tr>
```

However it appears that pushing tags and closing them later doesn't work.

So my question is:

What is the correct approach if I need to open a Tag (can be a `<tr>` element of a table, but it could also be a `<div>` or any other element that needs to be open, then several things  rendered inside and finally 
 it closed).

This is just a toy example of what I'm trying to do, but the problem is the same: I cannot open a tag and later close it.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. I would like to use `map` as a loop, not a `for` loop

Comment: Sembei, in this case, `.map` isn't the right approach. `.forEach` would be a proper alternative. That said, the duplicate is more about how you create a table / table cells in JS, which is what you're doing.

Comment: This is a toy example, probably I should have written the real example. In reality I have nested `<View>` in React-native with different `flexdirection` to achieve a Matrix of elements (which are not just text but `<Button>` elements)